# Why am I getting "weird" proportions from prob in knn()?

Tags: r, knn

I am trying to predict the Species (3 classes) from the iris dataset:

```
> head(iris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

I've created the numerical vectors tr and nw, which I use to subset iris so I can get training data and new data:

```
>knn5 <- knn(iris[tr, -5], iris[nw, -5], iris$Species[nw], k = 5, prob = TRUE)

>knn5

[1] versicolor virginica  virginica  versicolor virginica  setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     versicolor virginica 
[16] setosa     setosa     setosa     virginica  setosa     setosa     virginica  versicolor virginica  virginica  versicolor setosa     versicolor versicolor setosa    
[31] versicolor setosa     virginica  setosa     versicolor versicolor versicolor setosa     versicolor versicolor virginica  virginica  virginica  setosa     versicolor
[46] setosa     versicolor versicolor setosa     versicolor
attr(,"prob")
 [1] 0.4000000 0.4000000 0.4000000 0.6000000 0.4000000 0.6000000 0.6000000 0.4000000 0.3333333 0.6000000 0.6000000 0.5000000 0.6000000 0.6000000 0.6000000 0.5000000
[17] 0.4000000 0.6000000 0.4000000 0.6000000 0.6000000 0.6000000 0.6000000 0.6000000 0.6000000 0.8000000 0.4000000 0.6000000 0.6000000 0.6000000 0.4000000 0.6000000
[33] 0.4000000 0.6000000 0.8000000 0.6000000 0.6000000 0.6000000 0.6000000 0.6000000 0.6000000 0.6000000 0.6000000 0.5000000 0.6000000 0.3333333 0.4000000 0.6000000
[49] 0.6000000 0.6000000
Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
```

I understand that the predictions are very bad because in the knn I put the wrong vector for the labels; my question is not about that.

My question is, why am I getting 0.3333333 as values for prob? Since we are looking at 5 neighbors, I would expect that we only get values of the form n/5.

My initial guess was that these are places where there was a tie; however, I then realized that values of 0.4000000 are places where there must be ties (since we only have 3 classes, so the others must've voted 0.4 and 0.2). So I'm not sure about my guess anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are using `knn` from the `class` package.  Notice that it has an argument `use.all` described in the documentation like this:

> use.all
>
> controls handling of ties. If true, all distances equal to
>   the kth largest are included. If false, a random selection of
>   distances equal to the kth is chosen to use exactly k neighbours.

The iris data contains a pair of exact duplicate points

```
 iris[c(102,143),]
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
102          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica
143          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica
```

So if one of these points is the 5th nearest neighbor, they both are and 6 points will be considered - not just 5.